# Speech recognition doesn't work in Unity Hololens project

Tags: speech-recognition, hololens

I'm trying to create my own Unity project with speech recognition in Hololens. I copy pasted the instructions from [tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_101).

Literally copy pasted the `SpeechManager.cs` file and `SphereCommands.cs` file to my project but it won't budge. I tried putting some sounds in:
`KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized` to see if I get there (even before invoking anything), but I don't.

I start the `keywordRecognizer.Start()` (also added sounds to make sure I was there) but I have no idea if it's working afterwards.

The machine itself works, because if I open the Origami program, it recognizes my voice without issues. Also, saying "Hey Cortana" from the program also works.

I would copy the code, but it's just the file from the tutorial (even the phrases).

Comment: Maybe you do not have microphone enabled in project properties. You can share your project still. Or try to reproduce your problem with a sample project and share it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!
BTW, I also had to delete the compiled code and everything that Unity created earlier for it will work.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev you might consider adding your comment as an answer so others can easily see it, Then MosheS can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nikolay wrote in the comments, the answer is that I didn't enable the Microphone in the Unity Project (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player).
I also had to remove the UWP directory and rebuild in Unity is it will be relevant.