# Unity: Speech Recognition is not supported on this machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition, hololens

I have a problem with an Unity project. More specific with a HoloLens Application.
I have added the Keyword recognition from the MixedReality-Toolkit for unity. Until now everything worked fine. Today I had to reset my Laptop and install everything new. After the reset everything worked fine, but after activating my Windows 10 - Educational license in order to enable Hyper-V I get now the following Error message:

```
UnityException: Speech recognition is not supported on this machine.
UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognizer.CreateFromKeywords (System.String[] keywords, UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel minimumConfidence) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/Metro/runtime/SpeechBindings.gen.cs:47)
UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer..ctor (System.String[] keywords, UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel minimumConfidence) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Windows/Speech.cs:221)
MixedRealityToolkit.InputModule.InputSources.SpeechInputSource.Start () (at Assets/HoloToolkit/InputModule/Scripts/InputSources/SpeechInputSource.cs:72)
```

On other devices (I have tested it with Windows 10 Home and a bootable USB-Stick on the Laptop with Windows 10 Educational) the Voice recognition still works.
Does someone know how to solve this error?

**Edit:** Still have this problem. Does somebody found a new solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Having a look around [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552600/speech-recognition-doesnt-work-in-unity-hololens-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa),[2](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1190),[3](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/7187/speech-recognition-not-supported-on-this-machine)] I found several possible reasons:

- check if the Microphone is enabled in the Unity Project (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player) and rebuild
- if you updated to some new Windows version check if this broke Cortana & Speech services. This error happened when users updated to Windows 10 Creators and re-enabling Cortana made the trick
- set English (US) as primary language. It will install some additional speech recognition parts in Windows 10

PS also - for debugging purposes - as suggested [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone-devices.html) please check if the microphone is correctly detected checking the microphones list with this [Unity snippet](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone-devices.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but thanks for your answer.
- The microphone is enabled in the unity project and also gets detected by unity.
- The problem happened after I activated the Win 10 Educational Key and the following update. I already re-enabled Cortana in "gpedit.msc"
- The language switch didn't help aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that it is Windows 10 Educational. For some reason, I believe it only works on Win Home or Pro. I'd assume Win 10 Educational simple doesn't support Speech Recognition. In fact, I can't seem to find it but, I'm pretty sure there is documentation in setting up that you need either Windows 10 Home or Pro because it has certain features that Education does not.

Comment: It's definitely supported on Win 10 Educational. I used this on another educational system which worked fine with speech recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [Get to know me](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/getting-to-know-you-windows-10) enabled in your "Privacy/Speech, Inking, & Typing" menu.  See this and further suggestions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1190).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the "Get to know me" setting was already enabled and even after switching it off and on again it didn't fix my problem.

I can't open the link correctly that is provided by genereddick.

I've already tried to change the primary language before.